# Nvidia HDMI audio - Device not shown

Tags: nvidia, sound, hdmi, alsa, mint

Nvidia HDMI audio is a widely asked topic, but I've not been able to find the answer for my case.

Card displayed by `lspci`

```
$ lspci
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Device displayed by `aplay`

```
$ aplay -l
...
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

All outputs unmuted by `alsamixer`

[image: alsamixer outputs unmuted]

But the card does not appear in the Sound controller from System settings.

[image]

I'm currently using "nvidia-325" driver, but I tried "nouveau" and several other versions

My HDMI output is detected to be `/proc/asound/card2/eld#1.0`

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card2/eld#1.0
monitor_present     1
eld_valid           1
monitor_name        DENON-AVAMP

connection_type     HDMI
...
```

`speaker-test` does not find the device

```
$ speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:2,3

speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is hw:2,7
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -19,No such device
```

Can someone help me with my problem ? Or at least tell me why doesn't my device appear on sound settings ?

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues myself, but so far I have discovered that you need to test the different id's:

```
speaker-test -c [2/6] -r 48000 -D hw:2,[3,7,8,9]
```

`-c [2/6]` - test in stereo or 5.1

`hw:2,[3,7,8,9]` - 2 is the ID of your card, but as you can see from the list there are 4 different options. Only one of these give me audio.

I have no idea why this has to be so complicated, so I would love to see someone answer this more thoroughly, but I hope my answer at least helps you along the way.

Comment: I tried also 7, 8, 9 but without success

Answer (score 0):

When speaker-test fails, all other programs using alsa-lib should also fail with -D hw:2,3.

`Playback open error: -19,No such device` looks like speaker-test tries to open the wrong device:

```
prompt:> strace -o trace.log speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:2,3
prompt:> less trace.log
```

should reveal the device name alsa-lib tries to open.
From a first view, I'd say it's a bug in alsa-lib as it tries to open card0, device3 instead of card2, device3. A temporary fix would be to use symbolic links pointing to the correct device...